# Get Min() Value From SQL query when using an IN Array implode

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sql-server

**1)** I have checked and not found/read anything on SQL Min() and IN implode() together on the web yet.

**2)** This question is not about how to get a SQL Min() value from a  table/standard SQL query, or Get  a SQL Min() value from an array. I know how to do that.  I also know how to do it with Left Joining tables.

**This question is about getting a seperate SQL Min() value for each item in the array **when using** IN implode().**

PS: I have the intention of porting this script to SQL PDO  when I go live for security.

**The problem**
I have an array of id's (INT) that I get from a Sql script on the same page as this one.
The id's are input into the script below using implode().  The implode works fine all the names and the row colums for each member imploded member appears. When I add the SQL Min() to get the min amount EACH member has contributed,  I get one record with the min() amount found for ALL the imploded() members combined.

```
$memberid_arr = array('1','2','3');
```

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE memberid IN (".implode(',',$memberid_arr).") AND amount =( select min(amount) FROM members ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($conn->query($sql) === FALSE) {

echo"error";
die();

} else if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {


$name =   "".  $row['name']."";
$month =  "".  $row['month']."";
$amount = "".  $row['amount']."";

  $member_arr[] = array(
   
  "name"    => $name,
  "month"  => $month,
  "amount"=> $amount);
  }
   
echo json_encode($member_arr);
exit();
}
```

Comment: But `MIN()` value for `John` and `Jane` are not in `Jan`..

Comment: Please provide a proper minimal, reproducible example. What you're showing doesn't make any sense because the sample data column names don't correspond to those used in the query. I would suggest reading [tips for a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question).

Comment: sorry.. let me fix it..my example  is not meeting the standard

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: If you get the array from another SQL script, why don't you just merge the two with a `join`? Also, if you are using SQL Server, you should pass through a Table-Valued Parameter instead of using `implode` (which is inefficient and can cause SQL injection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the idea of a SELF Join that FaNo_FN provided, thank you (unfortunately failed to work for me but pointed in the right direction).  I successfully created a version that works for me that I can understand. **Result is:** For the PHP imploded ids Array entered into the Main script, all the min() INT value (£amount) will show for each user as these members have several amounts that they have contributed and I just wanted to find the least amount for each member.

**This answer demonstrates:**

1. A successful php implode() and applying it in another script in the same php page.
2. A successful self Join using Left Join method ( single database not joining two).
3. Successful use of  SQL min(), by getting the min value amount for each member.

I hope this helps other newbie’s as I wrote this in a manner we newbie’s could understand .

**User ID array from the SQL result from a script in the same page**

```
$memberid_arr = array('1','2','3');
```

```
$sql = "SELECT A.memberid , A.name, A.amount
FROM members A
LEFT JOIN members B ON  A.memberid = B.memberid
WHERE A.memberid IN (".implode(',',$memberid_arr).") AND A.amount = (
select min(A.amount) FROM members A WHERE A.memberid = B.memberid )
ORDER BY A.name;
";
```

Comment: It's good you've found a solution but now you're leaving this question open. If one is looking for an answer and found this, they won't think that the question has been solved since there's no accepted answer. Please accept your own answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain that `AND amount =( select min(amount) FROM members)` is the reason why it's not returning as desired. May I suggest you try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM members m 
JOIN (select Name,min(amount) minval FROM members group by name) v
ON m.name=v.name AND m.amount=v.minval
WHERE m.memberid IN (".implode(',',$memberid_arr).");
```

Slightly modifying your sub-query by adding `Name` and `group by name`; that way you'll get `MIN()` value for each `Name`... then turn it into `JOIN` instead of condition in `WHERE`.

Comment: Fano_FN ..Thank you!!!    Sometimes when you need a rope to get out of a hole a rope helps rather then being told I need to get a haircut first.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean but I'm glad it's helpful to you. ;)

Comment: @ FaNo_FN  you certainly have been helpful  to me and others who may face this same issue..   cheers :-)